# enable a template if i can get a non const reference from std::vector.front()

Tags: c++, type-traits

I do have a generic container like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct GenericContainer
{
    T& at(size_t index)
    {
        return data.at(index);
    }

    void append(const T& value)
    {
        data.push_back(value);
    }

    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

As you all know we can't get a non const reference to bool through std::vector.at function.
So this does not compile :  `bool& b = std::vector<bool>(true).front()`

For the same reason i can't call the function at on my GenericContainer.

I would like to enable the function at on my GenericContainer only if i can get a non const reference to T.

I tried to implement a type traits like that but it does not work, it returns true_type for bool and int, i am looking for false_type for bool and true_type for int. 
It is inspired from a is_copy_assignable type traits.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_ref_extractable_from_vector
{
    private:
    template <class U, class ENABLED = decltype(std::declval<U&>() = std::declval<std::vector<U>>().front())>
    static std::true_type try_assignment(U&&);
    static std::false_type try_assignment(...);

    public:
    using type = decltype(try_assignment(std::declval<T>()));
};


template<typename T>
using is_ref_assignable_from_vector_t = typename is_ref_extractable_from_vector<T>::type;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_ref_assignable_from_vector_v = is_ref_assignable_from_vector_t<T>::value;

static_assert(!is_ref_assignable_from_vector_v<bool>);
static_assert(is_ref_assignable_from_vector_v<int>);
```

i have no clue of why the assignment in the enable_if clause always compile.
i was hopping SFINAE to discard try_assignment(U&&) overload with U = bool.

thanks for your help.

ps : note that i'm a bit novice in meta programming so i will not be suprised if there is an obvious reason for that result :)

Comment: fwiw, the method is already "disabled" when `at` does not return a non-const reference, because in that case calling it  will not compile (though the error message might be a little cryptic)

Comment: The C++ standards folks made a bit of a gaffe with `std::vector<bool>`, which has a space optimized specialized implementation.  They should have made `std::vector_bool` space efficient custom implementation, but alas too late, that ship has sailed.

Comment: It's exactly `bool` and no other types for which `std::vector` is broken, and that's a defect in the standard (that remains for backwards compatibility reasons). You could specialise `GenericContainer<bool>` to not use `std::vector<bool>`

Answer (score 1):

It is *only* `std::vector<bool>` that has the broken specification, so the simplest way to write your trait is

```
template <typename T>
struct is_ref_extractable_from_vector : std::true_type {};

template <>
struct is_ref_extractable_from_vector<bool> : std::false_type {};
```

Alternatively, you could specialise `GenericContainer` for `bool` such that it doesn't use `std::vector<bool>`

```
class vector_bool {
    // all the members of std::vector

private:
    bool * data;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t capacity;
};

template<>
struct GenericContainer<bool> {
    bool& at(size_t index)
    {
        return data.at(index);
    }

    void append(const bool& value)
    {
        data.push_back(value);
    }

    vector_bool data;
}
```

Comment: Yes i did it first and it works fine. but i was looking for that specific type traits if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<bool>` does not return a `bool&`, but nevertheless this is completely fine:

```
std::vector<bool> x{0,0,0};
x.at(0) = false;
```

The reaons is that `x.at` returns a proxy (of type `std::vector<bool>::reference`) that allows you to write the element. If you want to check if it returns a non-const reference, you need to check that, not whether you can assign to it.

Alternatively you can tell `std::vector<bool>` apart from others by comparing its `reference` and `value_type` member aliases, because for a "normal" vector `reference` is just `value_type&`, while `std::vector<bool>::reference` is "special" (and `reference` is what is returned from `at`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, 
          typename U = void>
struct ref_is_ref_value : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct ref_is_ref_value<T,std::enable_if_t< std::is_same_v< typename T::reference, typename T::value_type&>,void>>
 : std::true_type {};

static_assert(!ref_is_ref_value<std::vector<bool>>::value);
static_assert(ref_is_ref_value<std::vector<int>>::value);
```

Of course, you could also just check if `value_type` is `bool`, because there is no other *weird* specialization of `std::vector`.

Comment: Ho yes that's an interesting way to approach that problem.
Thank you.
Anyway i m interesting in understanding why my code does not work.

Comment: @grenouilloux actually the whole answer is about why your code does not work. The solution i posted is just a curiosity to demonstrate how `reference` is special for `std::vector<bool>`. As mentioned you just need to check for `value_type` being `bool`. Your code does not work as expected because `x.at(0) = false;` is not an error

Comment: @grenouilloux you want to test if `at` returns a non-const reference, but what you actually test is whether you can assign to the result of calling `at` (whatever that is). And those two are not the same

Comment: Ho my god yes i think a got it ! that was not what that enable_if clause was entended to check. thks

Comment: to satisfy my curiosity do you have a way to write such a close ? a close that check if 
 bool& b = x.at(0) compile.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. That won't work, what you passed in is `bool`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 it will work, but for the wrong reason. Fixed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. I mean https://godbolt.org/z/nn4bdPdrj, which should not work since `bool& f(); f() = true;` is well-formed.

Comment: @康桓瑋 oh, I didnt realize that because I used the same typo as in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out. I will just delete the comment, I don't quite understand why it doesnt work atm

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++20, you can express this notion in a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
concept is_ref_extractable_from_vector = requires(std::vector<T> vec)
{
    {vec.front()} -> std::same_as<T&>;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Int extractable: " << is_ref_extractable_from_vector<int> << '\n';
    std::cout << "Bool extractable: " << is_ref_extractable_from_vector<bool> << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> Int extractable: 1
>
> Bool extractable: 0

Here the concept `is_ref_extractable_from_vector<T>` has the following requirements: Given an `std::vector<T>` named `vec`, `vec.front()` must compile and the return value of that expression must be the same as a `T&`.

Then you could use it in your struct like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct GenericContainer
{
    T& at(size_t index) requires is_ref_extractable_from_vector<T>
    {
        return data.at(index);
    }

    void append(const T& value)
    {
        data.push_back(value);
    }

    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

Now if you try to call `GenericContainer<bool>::at`, it will refuse to compile with an error message mentioning the constraint `is_ref_extractable_from_vector` but you can still use other `GenericContainer<bool>` functionality.

Comment: yes thank you but i forgot to mention that i can't used c++20 compilers...

Answer (score 0):

Your traits will not work because `std::declval<bool&>() = std::declval<std::vector<bool>>().front())` is still well-formed even if the latter is an rvalue.

You can determine whether `T&` can be bound to `vector<T>.front()` by defining a help function that only accepts lvalue reference:

```
template <class U>
static void fun(U&);
```

With this we can define our trait like:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_ref_extractable_from_vector
{
 private:
  template <class U>
  static void fun(U&);

  template <class U, class ENABLED = decltype(fun<U>(std::declval<std::vector<U>>().front()))>
  static std::true_type try_assignment(U&&);
  static std::false_type try_assignment(...);

 public:
  using type = decltype(try_assignment(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/bb8TWa6e8)